# How do I deconstruct/uncons a Symbol?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-level-computation

Given a type `s :: Symbol`, is there a way to define a type family by recursing over its characters one by one? I.e. as one would define a recursive function over a term-level string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - a type level `Symbol` is not a string composed of characters. `Symbol` is an infinite set of nominally distinct types which syntactically look like value level strings, but they have none of the properties of strings. In fact, other than being nominally distinct (and comparable) they have no other properties at all.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible in any released GHC, but if you want to do this, you can use my patch and join the discussion [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11342).

Comment: I'd love to accept this answer since it is exactly what I'd need for what I'm trying to do; but unfortunately it's not yet in GHC. I'll make sure to change the accepted answer to this if it lands in GHC one day.